# Creating content with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question regarding inserting content into my HTML webpage through an event listener. I'm trying to append three different list tags to the unordered list whenever the user clicks a button, but when I click nothing happens. I'm new to the javascript scene so any help will be appreciated!

HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact/Links</title>
    <link href="contactstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Giga&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <img id="signature" src="../images/Signature.svg" alt="Justin's signature">
    </header>
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <div>
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jmacow25?ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"><img src="../images/facebook.svg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/sockosam34/" target="_blank"><img src="../images/instagram.svg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/justin-mccown-695ba316b/" target="_blank"><img src="../images/linkedin.svg"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <p id="website-expansion">Click here to see where I learned how to code!<br><a href="#"><img src="../images/down.svg" id="button"></a></p>
        <p><a href="../landing/index.html">back to main page</a></p>
    </div>
    <footer>Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a></footer>
    <script src="contactscripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript code:

```
var appendBig = document.getElementById("links");
var textInfo = document.getElementById("website-explanation");
var buttonClick = document.getElementById("button");

buttonClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
    textInfo.remove();

    firstElement = document.createElement("LI");
    secondElement = document.createElement("LI");
    thirdElement = document.createElement("LI");

    firstElement.className = "bottomlist";
    secondElement.className = "bottomlist";
    thirdElement.className = "bottomlist";

    firstElementLink = document.createElement("a");
    secondElementLink = document.createElement("a");
    thirdElementLink = document.createElement("a");

    firstElement.appendChild(firstElementLink);
    secondElement.appendChild(secondElementLink);
    thirdElement.appendChild(thirdElementLink);

    firstElementImage = document.createElement("img");
    secondElementImage = document.createElement("img");
    thirdElementImage = document.createElement("img");

    firstElementImage.src = "../images/Codecademy.svg";
    secondElementImage.src = "../images/W3C_icon.svg";
    thirdElementImage.src = "../images/khanacademy.svg";

    firstElementLink.appendChild(firstElementImage);
    secondElementLink.appendChild(secondElementImage);
    thirdElementLink.appendChild(thirdElementImage);

    appendBig.appendChild(firstElement);
    appendBig.appendChild(secondElement);
    appendBig.appendChild(thirdElement);
});
```

Comment: Could it be a typo "website-explanation" (in the js) vs "website-expansion" (in the html)?  When I tried this code, I got console errors that complain about trying to remove the `textInfo` because of that typo.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

The id of the text info is `website-expansion` but you refer to `website-explanation`.

So change `<p id="website-expansion">` to `<p id="website-explanation">` and you are good to go! :)